# IE7 & IE8 javascript print function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm having a javascript issue I can't figure out.  I've taken a snippet of code that I got
[here](http://www.dougv.com/2007/10/17/printing-sections-of-a-web-page-using-divs-and-javascript-remote-scripting/) and am using it in [this](http://bvb.studiotwo.com/bvb/wishlist/) page.

The idea is that users can click the 'Print List' button and the listing is copied to a div within a hidden iframe and printed.  The printed page contains the the iframe source HTML with the list inserted properly.  However, in IE7 & 8, the printed page is the full parent page, not the iframe.  The behavior in IE9, Chrome and FF is correct.

I tried debugging the script but I couldn't see where it was going wrong.

Here's the code that the Print List click triggers:

```
function printSection(id) {
  if (document.getElementById('print_frame').contentDocument){
    theIframe = document.getElementById('print_frame').contentDocument;
  }
  else {
    theIframe = document.frames['print_frame'].document;
  }
  var thePrinter = theIframe.getElementById('print_section');
  var theCopy = document.getElementById(id);
  thePrinter.innerHTML = theCopy.innerHTML;
  parent.print_frame.printPage();
}
```

And here's the printPage() function:

```
function printPage() {
  window.parent.print_frame.focus();
  window.print();
}
```

I'd appreciate any help.  Please let me know if you need more information.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution might just be to use CSS media types to hide the content of the page and show an otherwise hidden element for print.

*CSS*

```
.print{display:none;}
@media print {
    .pagecontainer{display:none;}
    .print{display:block;}
}
```

*HTML*

```
<body>
    <div class="pagecontainer">
        Page content here
    </div>
    <div class="print">Only show this when printing</div>
</body>
```

Comment: MDN says css media types are supported in: Chrome 1.0, Firefox (Gecko) 1.0 (1.7), Internet Explorer 9.0, Opera 9.2, Safari 1.3. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@media